# Error on Spring REST webservice call

Tags: web-services, spring, rest

I have following webservice call

```
@RequestMapping(value = "modifyUser/{userDn}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    JSONObject modifyUser(@PathVariable String userDn, @RequestBody DirectoryUser directoryUser) {

        // Modify User
        boolean modifiedUser = this.authenticationService.modifyUser(userDn, directoryUser.getPassword(), directoryUser);

        // Build JSONObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("modifyUser", modifiedUser);
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

I am using following client method to access above REST webservice.

```
String url = "http://www.local.com:8080/CommonAuth-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/authentication/modifyUser/";
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url + "user6.external")

            JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
            ob.put("description", "updated");
            System.out.println(ob.toString());
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(ob.toString());
            entity.setContentType("application/json");
                    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

I always get "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method" error. What is wrong in my code.  I am able to access other webservice calls without using @RequestBody and using simple path variables. The issue is with @RequestBody and how i am using HttpPost.

```
public class DirectoryUser {
private String displayName;
    private String fullName;
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String description;
    private String country;
    private String company;
    private String phone;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;
    private boolean expirePassword = true;


    public String getDisplayName() {
            return displayName;
        }

        public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public void setCompany(String company) {
            this.company = company;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
        }

        public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public boolean isExpirePassword() {
            return expirePassword;
        }

        public void setExpirePassword(boolean expirePassword) {
            this.expirePassword = expirePassword;
            }

}
```

JSON string i am posting is {"description":"updated"}

Comment: This happens because Spring can't unmarshal the json you provide to a `DirectoryUser` instance. Can you post your code for that class? and an example of what the json you pass looks like.

Comment: please look above for the DirectoryUser code and json string i am posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
                try {
                /* your code */
if (httpResponse != null) {
                            InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
                            int n = 1;
                            while (n > 0) {
                                byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                                n = in.read(b);
                                if (n > 0)
                                    out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
                            }
                            System.out.println(out.toString());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Can you check what the status code says? Also, please check if it is HTTPS.

Comment: The issue is when request is going to server. not on what it returns and how it is processed.

Comment: IT is simple Http request. not HTTPS.

Comment: In web.xml is it <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Comment: Problem is not with url pattern. I have /api/* as url pattern.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring try to use Jackson for json marshall/unmarshall:

```
    private static final boolean jackson2Present =
        ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class.getClassLoader()) &&
                ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator", WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class.getClassLoader());
```

you need to add Jackson libs to your project.

Comment: I added Jackson parser and JSON converter. Now I am able to access the above web service without any errors.